# How to remove checkboxes in the form

Tags: javascript, html, dom, checkbox

```js
function newCheckbox(){
    var aLabel = document.form1.getElementsByTagName('label');
    var last = aLabel[aLabel.length-1];
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.appendChild(Box(aLabel.length));
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('      '+document.getElementById('text').value));
    last.parentNode.insertBefore(label, last);
    document.getElementById('text').value = '';
}

function Box(num){
    var elm = null;
    try {
        elm=document.createElement('<input type="checkbox" id="chk'+num+'">');
    }
    catch(e) {
        elm = document.createElement('input');
        elm.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
        elm.id='chk'+num;
    }
    return elm;
}

function delBoxes(){ 
    var texts = document.form1.getElementsByTagName('label');
    for(var i = 0; i<texts.length-1; i++){
        var chbox=Box[i];
        txt = texts[i];
        if(chbox.checked){
            chbox.parentNode.removeChild(chbox);
            txt.parentNode.removeChild(txt);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
form{
 color:blue;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin:100 0 0 50;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin-left:120;
 padding:100;
}

label{
 display:block;
}

input{
 color:blue;
 background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" name="form1">
            <div>
                <label>Checkbox text:<input type="text" id="text"></label>
                <input type="button" onclick="newCheckbox();"value="add">
                <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick = "delBoxes();"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to have a dynamic page that allows a user to add checkboxes to the page. Checkbox content is the input in the textbox.

When the user pushes the “add”-button checkboxes are created and shown. The user must have the ability to remove checkboxes by marking them. The code can add a new checkbox to the form but the deleting function does not work.

It seems that `chbox` is not created and the `if`-statement does nothing in the function `delBoxes`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Okey first of all i think you want to call a function in 
var chbox=Box[i]; right? So you have to use () not []. If no, you dont have any array created called Box, so therefore you have undefined variable chbox.

Comment: The argument to `createElement` is just a tag name like `input`, not a block of HTML like you tried.

Comment: Yes Redrif , you are right. I had missed it.  However it seems that the assignment var chbox=Box(i) does not work,.

Comment: var chbox=Box[i]; this is not how you call a function, chbox=Box(i); this is how you call it

Comment: The problem is that the function Box is creating element whether you are clicking on add or delete. So you create new element even when you are trying to delete it, but it will never get created or deleted, because newly created element is not checked so it wont be deleted, and you dont append it anywhere so it wont be created.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the whole script you have with this :

```
function newCheckbox() {
    var aLabel = document.form1.getElementsByTagName('label');
    var last = aLabel[aLabel.length-1];
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.appendChild(Box(aLabel.length));
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('      '+document.getElementById('text').value));
    last.parentNode.insertBefore(label, last);
    document.getElementById('text').value = '';
}

function Box(num) {
    var elm = null;
    try {
        elm=document.createElement('<input type="checkbox" class="chk">');
    }
    catch(e) {
        elm = document.createElement('input');
        elm.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
        elm.className='chk';
    }
    return elm;
}

function delBoxes(){ 
   var texts = document.form1.getElementsByTagName('label');
   var chbox = document.form1.getElementsByClassName('chk');
   for(var i = 0; i<texts.length-1; i++){
       if(chbox[i].checked){
           chbox[i].parentNode.removeChild(chbox[i]);
           texts[i].parentNode.removeChild(texts[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by those two comments above. Is it not working?

Comment: When I used the codes above. I have following error: object does not  support property or method getElementsByClassName. Add-button works as before but not delete-button.

Comment: Ok im going to edit my answer. Check it and tell me if it works now. Or what error you are getting now

Comment: object does not support property or method getElementsByClassName

Comment: what webbrovser are you using? IE 8?

Comment: The code works perfectly with IE aich Firefox but not with Chrome.

Comment: What? I am trying it in chrome and it works :-) What version of chrome do you have? Did you try ctrl+r or ctrl+f5?

Comment: You are right , it works , I used free javaScript editor and its own browser.It seems that it is not so good tool. Many thanks for your help,

Comment: You can check the question as answered with my answer then :-) I would appreciate it